# Graph API '/feed' connection is requiring an access token even for Public data on a Page

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

Kindly help me in understanding this:

Suppose I'm working with: http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola

http://graph.facebook.com/cocacola/feed was working but today its returning "An access token is required to request this resource."

Did the page owner changed something on it? If I'm the page owner how can I make it available without access token and how can I make it require the access token?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm seeing the same behavior for a page I'm working on as well. Trying to retreive public posts by calling to http://graph.facebook.com/fb_id_here/posts Guess it's a problem on Facebooks end?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently it was a design change scheduled for Friday, June 3rd 2011... You need an access token to access posts and feed now. This is covered in the [documentation for the Page object](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#connections)

http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/509/

Answer (score 2):

The API now requires authentification.

It is still possible to access the feed by RSS, for public pages https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID&format=rss20

Exemple (for facebook itself)
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=20531316728&format=rss20

Comment: to add to this - you can also get the feed in JSON by replacing 'rss20' with 'json'. For example: https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=20531316728&format=json