# Get facebook page feed

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, oauth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing graph feed to public and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234822/changing-graph-feed-to-public-and-private)

I'm building a website where I want to pull a pages wall posts (which is publicly available, you don't need to be logged into FB to see its contents), however when I try to get the data using the open graph protocol using:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/<PAGEID>/feed
```

I get a response that says I need a valid access token to retrieve the contents.  I want to be able to pull this all on the server side, so I don't need the end user to have to be logged into facebook to see the contents of the feed.

How do I go about grabbing this data as simply as possible (in php)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to grab the data in a most simple way is just to get its RSS feed which should be publicly available for everyone, example:
https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID&format=rss20

hope this helps

Comment: This sadly doesn't seem to work anymore...

Comment: Yeh how annoying! Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to generate Access Token:

Quering this URL:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&
response_type=token
```

When you provide you **APP_ID** you will get the access token that you can use:

Here is more info on the topic: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/#applogin

Here is another great tool: [Facebook API Graph Explorer](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/) - it will generate automaticly access token for you and you can test everything.