# Why does a public page feed require an access token?

Tags: json, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Changing graph feed to public and private](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234822/changing-graph-feed-to-public-and-private)

Why is it that the graph api now requires an access token for a **public** feed?

i.e. You can see a feed publicly on that page without even being logged into facebook, yet you can't parse it using the API.

Does this mean that it's now impossible to get the json of a public feed **on a page you do not own / have admin access to** in order to get an access token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is required since June 2011 to make it standard so that all API requests require access token and there are no more anonymous access to the API. It is still possible to access the RSS feed of the public pages.

https://www.facebook.com/feeds/page.php?id=PAGE_ID&format=rss20

hope this helps

Comment: how do you access that feed? also, what are the reasons for totally shutting out anonymous access?

Comment: I edited the post with RSS url

Comment: Reasons are mainly security and to block data brokers.

Comment: facebook have removed access to the json format public feed and are removing acess to the public rss feeds within 80 days or so, after that API access with a token will be the only way to acess the feeds